# sanitize input for ruby

Tags: ruby

Hallo I would like to sanitize input from Ruby, but simultaneously not have it mess up my strings containing foreign characters.

string1=string.downcase.gsub( /<(.|\n)*?>/, '' ).gsub(" ", "").gsub(",","").gsub("'","").gsub("_", "").gsub(";", "").gsub("-", "").gsub(":","").gsub(".", "").gsub("?", "").gsub("!", "").gsub("^","").gsub("%", "").gsub("$","")

The string needs to be stripped of spaces, apostrophes, and everything but letters (not sure about numbers), in addition to be sanitized. I am not sure if I forgot something, and probably something is redundant.

My code works OK as long as string does not contain harmless non-english characters such as accented letters, which I'd like it to deal with, but they break my code. My guess is that they are converted to %25 and all that stuff and afterwards they break. In fact it breaks even if I don't sanitize at all. How can I tell Ruby to handle non-english characters correctly? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Tried this http://ruby-unicode.rubyforge.org/doc/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this;

```
" ' ; te st".gsub(/\W+/, "") # "test"
```

Comment: Thank you for your extremely helpful answer which I will upvote when reputation allows. I wish to ask, can you compare these two? .gsub(/\W+/, "") and .gsub( /<(.|\n)*?>/, '' ) are they identical or not? thanks again a lot